# webapi, reading microsoft article, but contains error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am reading this article:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html.

and they say. you have to put this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TodoApi.Models;

    namespace TodoApi.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class TodoController : Controller
        {
            public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoItems)
            {
                TodoItems = todoItems;
            }
        }
    }
```

But where is `TodoItems`  declared?

Do I something wrong? Or is it mistake in the article?

Because If I put this in the file:

```
public ITodoRepository TodoItems { get; private set; }
```

The error goes away. But is this correct?

Comment: The tutorial is generated from a github project, and it includes code from files by line numbers. `public ITodoRepository TodoItems { get; set; }` appears on the line below the controller's constructor in the [source file](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnet/tutorials/first-web-api/sample/src/TodoApi/Controllers/TodoController.cs), so I'd guess it's simply the line numbers being slightly off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably mistake. You should declare it as:

```
    public class TodoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ITodoRepository TodoItems;

        public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoItems)
        {
            TodoItems = todoItems;
        }
    }
```

Here is using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) by constructor. 
So, I think that declaring of `TodoItems` as a `public` property is not a good idea. It should be a `private readonly` field that initializing only in constructor. In other case if you going to use inheritance it might be declared as a `protected`.

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: Just some general recommendations: Consider using some kind of naming convention for your private fields (like _todoItems). I would also recommend to put a guard clause in your constructor to prevent the class getting instantiated when someone tries to instantiate it with a null value, and throw a meaningfull exception...